# Better way to loop through array and reload data?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, for-loop, parse-platform

I'm trying to only display items that meet the criteria ( if location <= searchedDistance) but it seems like this is a very inefficient way to display this data. Does this function reload the entire tableview after each location is checked? If so, isn't this a horrible use of memory/time?

What's a better alternative?

```
var locations = [Int: Int]()



func searchSuccessful() {

var row: Int = 0
var section: Int = 0

for (index, location) in locations {

if location <= searchedDistance {

    self.theTableView.beginUpdates()
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: section)
    self.theTableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    self.theTableView.endUpdates()

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -reloadData reloads the entire `UITableView`. You should prepare the cells (as many as you want) and surround a single refresh by a set of `beginUpdates` & `endUpdates`.

Comment: I updated my question with the code. Just to clarify- this function is saying that for each location in locations that is less than or equal to the searchedDistance, reload that row? So the ones that are greater than searchDistanced aren't reloaded (not shown)?

Comment: Sorry! You helped tons..thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the begin/end update outside of the loop.

```
self.theTableView.beginUpdates()

// Do all the changes in a single place, surrounded by begin/end updates
for (index, location) in locations {
    if location <= searchedDistance {
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: section)
        self.theTableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
}
self.theTableView.endUpdates()
```

**Swift**

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: section)
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

**Obj-C**

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```